# How can I dynamically attach a scripting label to a newly created item in basil.js?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

Is there a way to add scripting labels to PageItems that are created in code, i.e. without using the Scripting Label panel?

My code looks like this:

```
var tf = b.text("Hello World", 200, 200, 300, 300);
```

Comment: Could somebody please add the tag "basil.js" for this as it is new? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Basil.js, but if you look at the [InDesign reference](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_PageItem.html#insertLabel) for a `PageItem`, you'll notice that there is a function called `insertLabel` that you can use to insert a label into a `PageItem`. You might also want to look at the `label` property.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tf = b.text("Hello World", 200, 200, 300, 300);
tf.label = "textframe_hello_world";
b.println(tf.label)
```

as josh said, the property "label" should do the trick.